# the derivative for a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

For the solution of the ODE $dy/dt=f(t,y)$, $f$ has to be Lipschitz for all $t$. So, if $f$ is a function that is not differentiable with respect to $y$ but Lipschitz, what can I say about $f_y$? Can I estimate some norm of it? I can't say $\lVert f_y\rVert_C$ because $f$ is not $C^1$, however, I can say that $f_y$ is defined in a weak sense and then this weak derivative is bounded (by the Lipschitz property) and I can estimate $\lVert f_y\rVert_{L^{\infty}}$ and have it bounded. Is that correct?

Comment: In the ODE $dy/dt=f(t,y)$ the function $f$ is understood to be given, while $y$ is a solution we don't know yet. It seems that your question has nothing to do with the function $y(t)$, hence it's not really a question about the differential equation. Is this correct?

Comment: I just thought what does it mean to be Lipshitz in case of non differentiability. I understand that we don't know range for $y$ and thus can't say what the constant that bounds derivative is, but we just know it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every Lipschitz function (on an open subset $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$) has a weak derivative which belongs to $L^\infty(\Omega)$. The $L^\infty$ norm of the derivative is bounded by the Lipschitz constant of the function.

Under appropriate assumptions on the geometry of $\Omega$ one can reverse this implication and obtain the global Lipschitz condition from the boundedness of the derivative.

Comment: every lipschitz function has a derivative a.e. by Rademacher, how do we know it has a weak derivative?

Comment: @abe.nong This is discussed e.g. on pp. 294-296 in Evans' PDE book: Let $U ⊂ ℝ^n$ be an open domain, $p ∈ (n, ∞], u ∈ W^{1,p}_{loc}(U)$. Then $u$ is differentiable almost everywhere and its gradient equals its weak gradient. Now, as user31373 wrote, every Lipschitz function on $U$ lies in $W^{1,∞}(U)$. Rademacher's theorem then follows as a corollary, together with the fact that every Lipschitz function is weakly differentiable.